# In React drop zone component how to have a image by default?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm using [`react-dropzone-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone-component#accessing-the-dropzone-object) npm, in which I want to display a default image to user. so that the user can edit that default image later.
I'm not able to add a default image in `react-dropzone-componen`t. Any work arounds please?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I'm using react-dropzone-component, to let user add an image as shown in this link, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone-component#accessing-the-dropzone-object , I want to have a default image to be displayed inside this dropzone component.